# no such element: Unable to locate element: validating the web element to be missing

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am looking to validate a scenario where a web element should not be displayed in selenium web driver but throwing an error "no such element: Unable to locate element:" let me know the ways to solve it..

```
try { 
    if (driver.findElement(By.id(Element_ID)).isSelected() == false) {
        //actions 
    } else { 
        //actions 
    } 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some code?

Comment: try {
   if (driver.findElement(By.id(Element_ID)).isSelected() == false)
   {
    //actions
    
   }
   else
   {
     //actions
   }
        
  } catch (Exception e)
  {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } this is the sample code i am trying

Comment: you still haven't presented enough information for anyone to assist with your debugging.  Does `Element_ID` actually have a value?  Is there an element with an `id` set to that value in your HTML? The error seems to indicate that the answer to one of those questions is no.

Comment: Element_ID has an actual value, it is a variable holding the ID of the Web element. Here i am not concerned of the error because of some actions I am performing the Element_ID (HTML Web component) is removed from web page dynamically i want to validate is it removed successfully or not that is the place where i am getting Unable to locate element error. Since element is taken out from the web page

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for this, below is the sample code i have used.

```
     try {
        String AU = driver.findElement(By.id(Element_ID)).getText();
        if( AU != "")
        {
            //Actions
        }

    } catch (Exception NoSuchElementException) 
    {
        //Actions

    }
```

Where Element_Id is a variable holding th ID of HTML web element.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

```
try {
    if (!driver.findElement(By.id(Element_ID)).isSelected()) {
        //Do your stuff
    }
} catch (TimedoutException | NoSuchElementException e) {
    //Do your stuff when element is gone or timed out while waiting
}
```

Example 2:

```
try {
    if (!driver.findElement(By.id(Element_ID)).getText().equals("some string") {
        //Do your stuff
    }
} catch (TimedoutException | NoSuchElementException e) {
    //Do your stuff when element is gone or timed out while waiting
}
```

Example 3:

```
try {
    if (!driver.findElement(By.id(Element_ID)).getAttribute("innerHTML").equals("some string") {
        //Do your stuff
    }
} catch (TimedoutException | NoSuchElementException e) {
    //Do your stuff when element is gone or timed out while waiting
}
```

Example 4:

```
try {
    if (!driver.findElement(By.id(Element_ID)).getAttribute("value").equals("some string") {
        //Do your stuff
    }
} catch (TimedoutException | NoSuchElementException e) {
    //Do your stuff when element is gone or timed out while waiting
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, didnt notice you answered your own question. Good Job!